# FAQ for specific Stack Exchange (meta) sites?

Tags: feature-request, site-recommendation, duplicate-questions, community, meta-faq

See [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)

That question and its answers are generic for all **Stack Exchange** sites and covers FAQ for all communities. Unlike that question, this question is asking about having FAQ for each specific **Stack Exchange** meta site *specific to the community*.

Each community has some Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ) that reappear in the meta of each community about specifics of that community, and which often result in duplicate questions. For example in:

**CHESS**:

> [Tool used to create chess analysis interactive diagrams in many chess stack exchange answers](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279/tool-used-to-create-chess-analysis-interactive-diagrams-in-many-chess-stack-exch/283#283)

**MATHEMATICS**

> [Math markup, diagrams, etc. — pointers please](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/480/math-markup-diagrams-etc-pointers-please)

Both these examples are about community specific markup in questions/answers to do with those communities. Notwithstanding, each community does have **Frequently Repeated Questions** and **FAQ** that reappear (and need to be deleted as duplicates)

**QUESTION**

> Unlike the question above **FAQ for Stack Exchange sites** which is about all communities, why can't each community or its meta have community specific FAQs?  Perhaps they could be a link added along the top to **QUESTIONS | TAGS | USERS | BADGES | UNANSWERED | FAQ**

The obvious benefit would be to reduce/eliminate duplicate messages and to make community specific Frequently Asked Questions easier to find.

Comment: Each site can have their own, and some sites *do* maintain their own list of FAQs. Every single Meta site has access to their own [meta-tag:faq] tag that can be applied by moderators.

Answer (score 8):

Every meta site has a [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag.  As with other red tags, its use is restricted to moderators.  Several sites that I'm active on use this tag to build site-specific additions to the global FAQ.  Sites can also link to these posts in close reasons, the moderator-editable parts of the help center, and in comments.

There's nothing stopping a site from building its own FAQ post on meta and linking all its FAQs there.  It would be best to cast this as a *site-specific* FAQ and then link to the one here on Meta.SE -- no point in repeating stuff that's already been written.  But yes, you can have a site-specific FAQ -- go ahead and build it.  It won't be directly in the header links (neither is the general FAQ), but it can be linked from all the right places.

Here's one example of how sites use this.  The [Mi Yodeya FAQ](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) has, at this writing, nine questions -- small enough to browse.  Here are some topics that don't come up on most other sites -- you wouldn't expect to find them in the main FAQ -- but matter a lot to us:

- [Can I consult Mi Yodeya as I would a rabbi?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734/472) (Law and Health have similar concerns; I don't know if they have FAQ posts about it)
- [Mi Yodeya glossary](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/581/472): 'cause discussions of Jewish law, texts, and traditions sure do involve a lot of words visitors might not know, but the site is for everybody and not just insiders.
- [Purim Torah policy: allowed, but regulated](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/797/472): within the Jewish community there is a tradition for a certain type of silliness for this holiday.  This post talks about the boundaries we place around silly Q&A as part of the festivities.
- [What are some mistakes non-Jewish people should avoid when asking questions on this site?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32/472): this question was asked by a visitor, not a site regular.  This post seeks to reassure while warning of just a few things that people trying to be careful might want to be careful about.

The Mi Yodeya FAQ doesn't cover topics from the general FAQ; instead, we link to the latter in the tag wiki.